# PostgreSQLの削除SQLについて

Tags: postgresql

以下の組み合わせテーブルから
A番号とB番号が同じグループIDであるものを削除するSQLを作成したいと思っています。
抽出するSQLを作成したのですが、削除するSQLがうまく作れません。
アドバイスいただけると嬉しいです。

抽出するSQLを作成しました。

```
SELECT
    組み合わせテーブル.ID,
    組み合わせテーブル.A番号,
    組み合わせテーブル.B番号,
    InnerJoinTB1.番号,
    InnerJoinTB1.グループID,
    InnerJoinTB2.番号,
    InnerJoinTB2.グループID
FROM 
    組み合わせテーブル
INNER JOIN 
    番号テーブル AS InnerJoinTB1 ON 組み合わせテーブル.A番号 = InnerJoinTB1.番号
INNER JOIN 
    番号テーブル AS InnerJoinTB2 ON 組み合わせテーブル.B番号 = InnerJoinTB2.番号
WHERE
    InnerJoinTB1.グループID != InnerJoinTB2.グループID
```

取得したい組み合わせテーブルのIDが取得できていることを確認したのですが、
組み合わせテーブルから該当するレコードを削除するSQLをどのように構築していいのかよくわかりません…
単純にSELECT箇所をDELETEにすればよいのかと考えたのですが、INNER JOINしているため、うまくいきませんでした。

```
DELETE
FROM 
    組み合わせテーブル
INNER JOIN 
    番号テーブル AS InnerJoinTB1 ON 組み合わせテーブル.A番号 = InnerJoinTB1.番号
INNER JOIN 
    番号テーブル AS InnerJoinTB2 ON 組み合わせテーブル.B番号 = InnerJoinTB2.番号
WHERE
    InnerJoinTB1.グループID != InnerJoinTB2.グループID
```

番号テーブル
ID グループID 番号
100 1 1000
200 1 2000
300 2 3000
400 3 4000

組み合わせテーブル
ID A番号 B番号
1 1000 2000
2 3000 1000
3 4000 1000
4 2000 1000
※A番号とB番号が番号テーブルに紐づく

Answer (score 1):

`組み合わせテーブル.ID`でレコードが一意になるのであれば、元のSELECT文を副問い合わせにして削除対象のIDを指定するのがよいと思います。

```
/* 例 */
DELETE
FROM
    組み合わせテーブル
WHERE
    組み合わせテーブル.ID IN (
        SELECT 組み合わせテーブル.ID
        FROM
            組み合わせテーブル
        INNER JOIN
            番号テーブル AS InnerJoinTB1 ON 組み合わせテーブル.A番号 = InnerJoinTB1.番号
        INNER JOIN
            番号テーブル AS InnerJoinTB2 ON 組み合わせテーブル.B番号 = InnerJoinTB2.番号
        WHERE
            InnerJoinTB1.グループID != InnerJoinTB2.グループID
    )
```

あるいは、PostgreSQL拡張を用いるのであれば、`using`句を用いて`番号テーブル`を指定する方法もあると思います。(参考: [PostgreSQLのDELETE文の説明](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/10/html/sql-delete.html))